# How to simplify the following statement?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do I simplify the following statement?

$(x \lor y \lor z) \land (x \lor \lnot y \lor \lnot z)$

I have worked out the truth table:
[image: Truth table]

How do I reduce the statement further though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what is considered more 'simplified'

You could take out the $x$ that both terms have in common:

$(x \lor y \lor z) \land (x \lor \neg y \lor \neg z) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Distribution)}$

$x \lor ((y \lor z) \land (\neg y \lor \neg z))$

And you could even rewrite that last bit as an $XOR$:

$z \lor (y \oplus z)$

But is any of that considered 'simpler'?

Comment: I had the same question as well, because it's going to give the same truth values,but perhaps it meant shortening the length of the original statement. This would work. Also, just to clarify, the final statement was supposed to be x∨(y⊕z), right?

Comment: +1, The form $z \vee (y \oplus z)$ is much easier to read and understand.